# What Tool for creating, experiencing new layouts and designs?

Tags: css, layout, user-interface, editor, user-experience

I am developing WebApps with Backbone, node, jQuery and so on.

In my beginnings I have used Twitter Bootstrap for designs. 
Then I started to use own designs which I have created with the Chrome Addon Stylebit which allows to modify CSS in real time.

Unfortunately this is very time expensive at the end.

So I decided to develope the design by side with some editor and then rewrite this design per hand as CSS. I have read this is a common practice and most use photoshop for this task.

Is photoshop still recommend or are there other tools which should be used?

(I actually do not want a full WYSIWYG. Just something to test designs and layouts in general)

Cheers and happy new year,
Bodo

Comment: Know what's good for wireframing webpages?  HTML/CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon I totally agree but how do you handle all of these small things like margins, shadows, fonts, colors and so on. They always take a lot time.

Comment: If website design was quick and easy, then everyone would be doing it.

Comment: There's a big difference between wireframing layouts and doing all the decorations (shadows/colors/etc).  Pencil and paper is the fastest way to prototype multiple layouts.  Changing all that other stuff is simple with a CSS preprocessor (Sass, LESS, etc.).

Comment: Okay could you write this as answer then I can mark it.

Comment: That's not an answer, that's just lame. Nothing wrong with trying to improve developer productivity. It's a good question for those working on complex data-centric business apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the short answer no. There isn't a tool that I know of that will allow you to build layouts in code easily that isn't a full WSIWIG solution like Dreamweaver, Aptana etc.

For testing out designs you would normally build  wire frames such as the ones you see from Balsamiq. There are other tools as well, Axure, Pencil and others. Do a search for wire frame software.

As a Sr. UX Architect I've heard and seen people mockup what they're building in Html and CSS. While this can work. You might as well continue and just build it if you're going to invest the time, effort and money into writing code.

Spin over to my ["User Experience"](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=72842&trk=hb_side_g) group on Linkedin and ask the question there. Your going to get a ton of answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching to find Wireframing and Mockup tools.Then you can use **Balsamiq Mockups**

[image]

**It's having features like**

1. Low-Fi Sketch Wireframes
2. Click-Through Prototypes
3. UI Components & Icons
4. Export to PNG or PDF etc

You can get more details from [**Balsamiq Mockups Here**](http://www.balsamiq.com/)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out ForeUI (http://www.ForeUI.com/), which allows you to build layouts visually and export your design to HTML5 simulation.  You can also manually modify the generated code to fit your needs.

[image: ForeUI in Mac OS]

Some interesting examples are available on http://www.foreui.com/store/

Answer (score 0):

I'm working for Pidoco.

It's a german company based in Berlin and we develop a online prototyping tool.

We have nice features like:

Interactive prototypes
Collaboration and invitations
iOS App to simulate mobile prototypes (Android is coming soon)
You can start with a 30 days free trial and then plans are starting at 9$ per month.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete list of mockup tools:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools